# NetBeans Java code completion is way too eager to please

Tags: java, netbeans, code-completion

Is it normal that the default behavior for code completion when editing Java is the following?

1. If I `import` a package, after typing the first `.`, any key I press results in the first item in the list being selected
2. Sometimes while typing keywords like `public` and `protected`, NetBeans will make some wild leaps and insert `private` after just a `p` or `pu` are typed!
3. In general, it tends to make some big guesses in terms of autocompletion, guesses that are not supported by my previous input at all.

I feel like this *cannot* be the desired behavior for every user. Is there a way to make the code completion not autocomplete anything, or at least make it way less eager?

Edit: To be clear, I do not want to have to disable the sometimes-useful "Autopopup Window." I want the window to eagerly appear with tips and suggestions for methods, syntax, whatnot - I just don't want NetBeans to try to guess what I want, because it is wrong 90 - 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Netbeans are you using because that doesn't seem to be the behaviour I am seeing in 7.1.

AutoCompletion popups don't appear until I hit Ctrl+Space.
If I type "p" and then hit Ctrl + Space, the popup shows "private", "protected" and "public". I can either keep typing (and the list gets smaller as possible matches are removed) or use the cursors to select the word I want and hit Enter.

If there is only one logical option e.g. I start typing "pu" and then hit Ctrl+Space, then Netbeans inserts "public" automatically (though this can be turned off).

Code templates are a different story, I have them set to be activated using Shift+Space. As far as I know, templates don't show any popups. Anyone who likes pain can consider changing the activation key to just Space :P

Answer (score 0):

I definitely share your complaints, especially re: 1. A quick google search reveals [ways to turn off autocomplete](http://offtheline.net/2007/12/11/netbeans-6-0-cheat-sheet):

> AutoComplete drives me crazy. I’ve always hated it – I feel like it
>   slows my computer down and sometimes it even seems to derail me in the
>   middle of typing something because the window comes up and somehow
>   snags focus. I turn it off under Options, Editor, General (uncheck
>   Auto Popup Completion Window).

Comment: I know about turning the "auto popup completion window" off, but I do rather like having it around to "guide" my coding when I can't remember an exact method name or signature. I just don't want NetBeans to make these gigantic leaps of faith as to what I want

Answer (score 0):

Item 2) sounds more like the "code template" feature rather than the auto-completion.

If that gets in your way, you have two options:

1. change the key that "triggers" the code-template expansion (e.g. from "Space" to "Tab"
2. remove all two-stroke templates (or any other abbreviation that you would rather not have)

Both can be done under "Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates"